# Как обращаться к каждому элементу Spinner'a в AndroidStudio?

Tags: java, android

есть следующий код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String[] langChoose = {"Русский", "English"};
    TextView info;
    Button ruLang;
    Button engLang;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayAdapter<String> langChooseAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, langChoose);

        langChooseAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        Spinner langChoose = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.langChoose);

        langChoose.setAdapter(langChooseAdapter);

        langChoose.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }

        });
        info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
    }
}
```

никак не могу найти как обращаться отдельно к каждому элементу спиннера, хочу отследить нажатие по одному из них конкретно, что бы менять язык текста

Comment: Не вполне понятна ваша проблема. Разве onItemSelected - не делает то, что вам нужно?

Comment: Имею ввиду, например при помощи findViewById можно обратиться по айди из xml, мне необходимо подобным образом обратиться к элементу из данного спиннера

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду извне адаптера менять вьюхи в отображаемом списке - то это плохая идея, неправильный подход. Тут надо так делать: создать свой собственный адаптер, менять данные для адаптера и уведомлять его об этом - тогда вызовется метод адаптера, ответственный за отрисовку (вроде бы getView) и отображение изменится. Как с обычной разметкой работать тут не выйдет.